# Django doesn't save PATCH request to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to `PATCH` an object in my database via the Django REST Framework. The request gets handled in my backend and the updated attribute (`friendship_status`) is part of the response I receive. But: the attribute is not updated in the database. Or, at least it does not show in the Django Admin.

What am I missing here?

**Request**

```
fetch(host + '/api/relationships/' + relationshipID + '/', {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Token " + token,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    friendship_status: 'requested',
  }),
})
// plus some .then() method calls
```

**Response**

```
headers:Headers
ok:true
status:200
statusText:undefined
type:"default"
url:"http://localhost:8000/api/relationships/27aae52c-020b-4d3d-8037-03ae005fb7ef/"
_bodyInit:"{"id":"27aae52c-020b-4d3d-8037-03ae005fb7ef","friendship_status":"requested","is_blocked":false,"created":"2018-10-22T09:53:50.550167","modified":"2018-10-22T10:35:16.657392","from_user":29,"to_user":28}"
_bodyText:"{"id":"27aae52c-020b-4d3d-8037-03ae005fb7ef","friendship_status":"requested","is_blocked":false,"created":"2018-10-22T09:53:50.550167","modified":"2018-10-22T10:35:16.657392","from_user":29,"to_user":28}"
__proto__:Object
```

**DefaultRouter**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'relationships', relationship_views.RelationshipViewSet)
```

**ModelViewSet**

```
class RelationshipViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Relationship.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RelationshipSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Relationship.objects.filter(from_user=self.request.user)
```

**ModelSerializer**

```
class RelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    from_user = AccountSerializer(read_only=True)
    to_user = AccountSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Relationship
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Model**

```
class Relationship(models.Model):

    FRIENDSHIP_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('ignored', 'Ignored'),
        ('requested', 'Requested'),
        ('accepted', 'Accepted'),
    )

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relationships')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    friendship_status = models.CharField(choices=FRIENDSHIP_STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Created'))
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('Last modified'))
```

**admin.py**

```
 @admin.register(Relationship)
 class RelationshipAdmin(ExcelExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('id', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'friendship_status', 'is_blocked', 'created', 'modified')
     search_fields = ('from_user', 'to_user')
```

Comment: Why do we have `read_only=True` when we want to `update`/PATCH the data ?

Comment: can you please post the model `Relationship` as well?

Comment: @MohammadUmair: That's a good point but I am not updating the `from_user` or `to_user` field in my `PATCH` request. Removing those two lines also does not make the updated attribute appear in the Django admin.

Comment: @AhmedHosny: `Relationship` model added.

Comment: @steventilator Thanks, I guess that the value you are sending in patch request does not match any of choices of `friendship_status`. Can you tell us more about the payload you send and what the status code returned?

Comment: @AhmedHosny I added my request and the response I get. I don't think a wrong value is causing this behaviour, though. I tried sending 0 instead of the string 'requested' and Django REST framework responded with '0 is not a valid choice.'

Comment: One more thing just to have a full idea of what is going on; Now I think the problem might be in you django admin pages. The way to verify is to `python manage.py shell` `r = Relationship.objects.get(id="27aae52c-020b-4d3d-8037-03ae005fb7ef") ` and check the `r. friendship_status`

Comment: Why you override get_queryset? Remove that and try partial update

Comment: @AhmedHosny Looks like the problem is indeed in the Django admin pages. If I check the `friendship_status` in the shell, the returned value is 'requested'. Also, if I manually change the `friendship_status` in the Django admin page, it says the change was saved successfully but the value is still None (---). I will add the admin.py to my question. Maybe you could have a look at it?

Comment: Okay, I solved problem by running `docker-compose build`. Does anybody know why that was needed? Anyway, thanks for your time and help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by rebuilding my Docker containers: `docker-compose build`.